How can I efficiently filter and process large CSV files with pandas?
I'm working with a CSV file that has millions of rows and several columns. I need to:
Filter the rows based on certain conditions (e.g., age > 30 and salary > 50000).
Perform some operations on the filtered data (e.g., add a new column that calculates the yearly bonus as 0.1 * salary).
Save the processed data to a new CSV file.
However, I keep running into memory issues because the file is too large to load entirely into memory. Here's what I've tried so far:
python
import pandas as pd

# Load the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('large_file.csv')

# Filter rows
filtered_df = df[(df['age'] > 30) & (df['salary'] > 50000)]

# Add a new column
filtered_df['bonus'] = 0.1 * filtered_df['salary']

# Save to a new CSV file
filtered_df.to_csv('processed_file.csv', index=False)

This works well for smaller files, but when the file size grows, it crashes due to memory limitations.
I've read about dask and chunk processing, but I'm unsure how to implement them in my case. Could someone provide a clear example of how to process large CSV files efficiently?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

See here for an example of chunking: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962187/530160 See here for an example of appending to a CSV file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530542/how-to-add-pandas-data-to-an-existing-csv-file (You'll need this if you don't want to hold the final CSV in memory all at once.)

may want to try polars: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73033580/why-polars-scan-csv-is-even-faster-than-disk-reading-speed

If all the data cannot fit into memory, and if the logic allows one line at a time processing, you could also considere not using pandas at all. The good old csv module is far less powerful and sexy than pandas, but it can handle unlimited data one row at a time...

As suggested by the answer indicated by Nick ODell, you can process your file in smaller chunks using the chunksize option.
You can also do some optimization:
Do you really need all columns of the original csv? You can import only columns you need using the usecols option.
The default type for floats is float64 and for integers is int64, do you really need such a precision? I suppose there are no employees older than 127 years or having a wage > 4 billions. You can save memory using shorter data types using the dtype option.
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame()
with pd.read_csv('large_file.csv', chunksize=1000, usecols=['age', 'salary', 'other_col'], dtype={'age': 'int8', 'salary': 'int32', 'other_col': 'bool'}) as reader:
    for n, chunk in enumerate(reader):
        print(f"Chunk number {n}  memory used {chunk.memory_usage().sum()} bytes")
        temp = chunk [(chunk['age'] > 30) & (chunk['salary'] > 50000)]
        filtered_df = pd.concat([filtered_df, temp], axis=1)
filtered_df['bonus'] = 0.1 * filtered_df['salary'] 
filtered_df.to_csv("my_result_file.csv")

